# System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteNonQuery: la propiedad Connection no se ha inicializado.'

Tags: visual-studio

Estoy realizando un código para añadir, eliminar y actualizar datos y al ejecutar me devuelve el error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteNonQuery: la propiedad
> Connection no se ha inicializado.

La conexión es con SQL Server. Alguien podría decirme la razón?

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form2
    Private Sub btnRegresar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRegresar.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnInsertar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnInsertar.Click

        Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP-F9LH3NF5\DAOSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=PracticaEvaluada;Integrated Security=True")
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Estudiantes]
            ([NombreCompleto]
            ,[CodigoEstudiante])
        VALUES
            ('" + txt2NombreEstudiante.Text + "', '" + txt2CodigoEstudiante.Text + "')")

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        MessageBox.Show("Datos Insertados Exitosamente!", "Informacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        con.Close()

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnEliminar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEliminar.Click
        Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP-F9LH3NF5\DAOSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=PracticaEvaluada;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("DELETE From [dbo].[Estudiantes]
        Where [NombreCompleto] = '" + txt4CodigoEstudiante.Text + "', '" + txt4NombreEstudiante.Text + "'", con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Datos Eliminados Exitosamente!", "Informacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        con.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnActualizar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnActualizar.Click
        Dim con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP-F9LH3NF5\DAOSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=PracticaEvaluada;Integrated Security=True")
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE [dbo].[Estudiantes]
    SET [NombreCompleto] = '" + txt3NombreEstudiante.Text + "',[CodigoEstudiante] = '" + txt3CodigoEstudiante.Text + "'WHERE [NombreCompleto] = '" + txt3NombreEstudiante.Text + "'", con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Datos Actualizados Exitosamente!", "Informacion", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        con.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. Deberías especificar en que metodo de lanza la excepción.

Comment: Creo que debes ponerle la etiqueta de VBA o `Visual Basic`

Comment: Hola.... En el método de botón Insertar, al definir el SqlCommand no le has puesto el segundo parametro que es la conexión.`Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(query, connection)`

Answer (score 0):

Creaste la conexión pero nunca le informas al SqlCommand que conexion va  utilizar
puedes utilizar estas 2 formas

FORMA 1

```
cmd.Connecion = con
```

FORMA 2

Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("TU SENTENCIA" , con)

Te recomiendo utilizar un modelo  [3 CAPAS](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures) y [PROCEDIMIENTOS ALMACENADOS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15)